# SSIS 2008 - File Delete not working, but File Move does

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, permissions

We've run into a strange issue.  We have some SSIS 2008 packages that had been working fine for quite a while.  As part of the work flow they copy files to a backup folder, and then delete the original file.  (No, I don't know why they didn't just make it a File Move task.)  Suddenly, the delete task has stopped working.  It's not just our packages either, it's the packages of a different group on a different SSIS server.  Same target folders though.

The server team has gone over the folder permissions, the account the jobs run under have full access.  And, if it was an access issue, how could we move the file but not delete it?

Comment: Is there a different higher privileged account you could try *just to make sure* it's not a permissions issue? For NTFS permissions, removing the ability to delete also annoyingly removes the ability to rename a file. Could you create a file there manually as the current SSIS package user and try to rename/delete it?

Comment: Is it returning an error message when it tries to delete the file and fails?

Comment: Did you recently change or upgrade the virus scan software?

Comment: Assuming you're using a network share and accessing using windows authentication (SQL Agent service account?), I believe in addition to ensuring the NTFS permissions are set properly (which it appears you've already done), you need to ensure the permissions on the file share are set properly as well. Be default, a file share has only read access.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the answer.  The file server we're using is Linux based.  It is case sensitive, but doesn't throw an error if you use the wrong case.  Was a very tough issue for us to track down.